# Can I select just a child div in CSS with JavaScript, without selecting the parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a calendar. When the user clicks on a "day" element, I want a drop-down time for them to select. I have that working. The issue I am having is that when the drop-down time is selected, so is the parent "day" element. This creates another dropdown with time when the first time was selected. How can I create an *if* statement in JavaScript that only looks for a child element click, and not a parent?

JavaScript:

```
function create_dropdown(day){
        var insertdiv = document.createElement('select');
        insertdiv.className = "times";;
        day.appendChild(insertdiv);
        for(var i=0;i<times_full.length;i++) {
            insertdiv.options[insertdiv.options.length] = new Option(times_full[i], i);
        }
    }

document.querySelectorAll(".day").forEach(day => {
    day.addEventListener("click", event => {
        event.currentTarget.classList.toggle("selected");
        if(event.currentTarget.classList.contains('selected'))
        {
            day.style.backgroundColor='#B0E0E6';
            create_dropdown(day);
        }
        else
        {
            day.style.backgroundColor='transparent';
        }
    });
});


var times_full = [
  "12:00 AM",
  "1:00 AM",
  "2:00 AM",
  "3:00 AM",
  "4:00 AM",
  "5:00 AM",
  "6:00 AM",
  "7:00 AM",
  "8:00 AM",
  "9:00 AM",
  "10:00 AM",
  "11:00 AM",
  "12:00 PM",
  "1:00 PM",
  "2:00 PM",
  "3:00 PM",
  "4:00 PM",
  "5:00 PM",
  "6:00 PM",
  "7:00 PM",
  "8:00 PM",
  "9:00 PM",
  "10:00 PM",
  "11:00 PM"
];
```

A picture of elements:

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the drop down code I cannot be sure, but it sounds as though the click in the time is getting propagated also to the underlying day and you’d need to stop that. Can you show us the stuff that happens in clicking a time/ the dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

Keep your current code as-is, except add `if( even.target.parentElement.matches('.day') ) { }` inside the listener.

(`event.target` is the element that was actually clicked, whereas `currentTarget` is the element that has the attached listener).

```
document.querySelectorAll(".day").forEach( day => {
    day.addEventListener("click", event => {
        if( event.target.parentElement.matches('.day') ) {
            event.currentTarget.classList.toggle("selected");
            // etc
        }
```